# Pass parameters when autoloading library with CodeIgniter

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, autoload

I am trying to auto load the facebook.php but it requires the app id and secret. Is it possible to pass parameters when auto loading a library in CodeIgniter ?

Comment: Is this facebook.php file a Codeigniter library file from somewhere or is another class that you've found somewhere?

Comment: Its the facebook.php from the facebook php-sdk

Answer (score 5):

I recently did [a blog post about this very topic](http://jondavidjohn.com/blog/2011/07/using-the-facebook-api-with-codeigniter).

The official facebook SDK plays very nice with Codeigniter and just requires you use a external config file to accomplish your goals of autoloading...

so you would just place a file `facebook.php` in your `config` directory with these contents

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

$config['appId']  = 'YOUR_APP_ID_HERE'; 
$config['secret'] = 'YOUR_APP_SECRET_HERE';
```

At this point loading the library should pick up this config while autoloading or otherwise.

Comment: I saw the tutorial but its not quite what I meant. I don't want to auto load only the config file and then load the php sdk every time in the controller, I want to auto load it so I can avoid that.

Comment: you are missing my point, if you have this config file in place, you can add `facebook` to the autoloader and it will automatically use this config file...

Answer (score 1):

You can write a wrapper which will pre-initialize lib using config settings and expose it on one of its public members.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html